# Suggestion for Curl with token

Tags: ssl, curl, token

I tried to access a server with

```
curl -H "X-Ath-Token: fb1ca943-f499-4c0c-...-7765847247f0" https://serverurl.com
```

I got

> "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate"

I used the same token approach the same url using firefox plugin "RESTClient" and it worked fine with 200.

Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: You could use the `--insecure` option to ignore the certificate error. Or better, use `--pinnedpubkey`

Comment: see CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_CAINFO